# JavaScript vs jQuery Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I was wondering what the difference between jQuery selectors `$("#fake-div)` and JavaScript selectors `getElementById("fake-div")`. First, are these even called JavaScript selectors?. I know jQuery returns the jQuery object whereas JavaScript selectors returns the DOM element; however, given these two blocks of code:

**jQuery Selector**

```
var post = $("#postid");
var reply_list = post.find(".replies_ul");
var current_reply = document.createElement("li");
current_reply.setAttribute("class", "reply_li");
reply_list.insertBefore(current_reply, reply_list.firstChild);
```

**JS Selector**

```
var content_list = document.getElementById("content_ul");
var current_post = document.createElement("li");
current_post.setAttribute("class","content_li");
content_list.insertBefore(current_post, content_list.firstChild);
```

The jQuery Selector ends up removing the list from the DOM when the last line of code is called, and the JavaScript selector successfully inserts the list item at the top of the list. I'm looking for an explanation as to what is going on.

Comment: `$("#postid")[0]` gets the DOM element.

Comment: What is you question? Do want to know the difference between jQuery and JS selectors, or do you want to know how to fix the jQuery code - which is a hotch-potch of jQuery and pure JS - to work as intended?

Comment: @Tomm Is there a downside to using a hotch-potch of jQuery and pure JS?  I wanted to know answers for both of the questions - but i understand now thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery `insertBefore` in your code is invalid, it takes two arguments whereas the jQuery accepts only one:

> [.insertBefore( target )](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)
>
> **Description**: Insert every element in the set of matched elements before the target.

And the *normal* one:

> [Node.insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)
>
> **Description**: Inserts the specified node before a reference element as a child of the current node.
>
> `parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement)`

Answer (score 1):

The difference is not on the selector but on the method / function that you are calling.

You are using the [jQuery `insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) function and comparing it with the [javascript insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) function.

In jQuery the `insertBefore` function has only one parameter and therefore you are using it wrong.

If you want to make use of the Javascript function `insertBefore` instead of the jQuery one, then you have to convert your jQuery object `reply_list` to a Javascript one.
You can do this by using `.get(0)` or  `[0]` like so:

```
reply_list[0].insertBefore(current_post, content_list.firstChild);

//or like this
reply_list.get(0).insertBefore(current_post, content_list.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first block of code, the `reply_list` is a jQuery object; meaning it doesn't actually have a `.firstChild` property.

Change it to this:

```
reply_list.get(0).insertBefore(current_reply, reply_list.get(0).firstChild);
```

Please note the differences between jQuery's ***[insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)*** and JavaScript's ***[insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)***